# How do zipkin do to merge span for search trace request?

Tags: html, trace, zipkin

In the zipkin web ui, when the request url is http://10.19.138.169:9411/zipkin/api/v1/trace/ae60bd175a61e820

I find the return response is 
[
    {
        "traceId": "ae60bd175a61e820",
        "id": "ae60bd175a61e820",
        "name": "client",
        "timestamp": 1511858133224433,
        "duration": 508444,
        "binaryAnnotations": [
            {
                "key": "lc",
                "value": "",
                "endpoint": {
                    "serviceName": "monitor-gw-http-c",
                    "ipv4": "10.19.138.169"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "traceId": "ae60bd175a61e820",
        "id": "19d69c3e93bc9040",
        "name": "post",
        "parentId": "ae60bd175a61e820",
        "timestamp": 1511858133239803,
        "duration": 490921,
        "annotations": [
            {
                "timestamp": 1511858133239803,
                "value": "cs",
                "endpoint": {
                    "serviceName": "monitor-gw-http-c",
                    "ipv4": "10.19.138.169"
                }
            },
            {
                "timestamp": 1511858133383290,
                "value": "sr",
                "endpoint": {
                    "serviceName": "monitor-gw-web",
                    "ipv4": "10.19.138.169"
                }
            },
            {
                "timestamp": 1511858133609368,
                "value": "ss",
                "endpoint": {
                    "serviceName": "monitor-gw-web",
                    "ipv4": "10.19.138.169"
                }
            },
            {
                "timestamp": 1511858133730724,
                "value": "cr",
                "endpoint": {
                    "serviceName": "monitor-gw-http-c",
                    "ipv4": "10.19.138.169"
                }
            }
        ],
        "binaryAnnotations": [
            {
                "key": "ca",
                "value": true,
                "endpoint": {
                    "serviceName": "",
                    "ipv4": "127.0.0.1",
                    "port": 43928
                }
            },
            {
                "key": "http.path",
                "value": "/security/gateway",
                "endpoint": {
                    "serviceName": "monitor-gw-web",
                    "ipv4": "10.19.138.169"
                }
            },
            {
                "key": "http.path",
                "value": "/security/gateway",
                "endpoint": {
                    "serviceName": "monitor-gw-http-c",
                    "ipv4": "10.19.138.169"
                }
            },
            {
                "key": "sa",
                "value": true,
                "endpoint": {
                    "serviceName": "",
                    "ipv4": "127.0.0.1",
                    "port": 8090
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "traceId": "ae60bd175a61e820",
        "id": "16eefe087852af41",
        "name": "ennmonitorsecuritygatewayserver/put",
        "parentId": "19d69c3e93bc9040",
        "timestamp": 1511858133393425,
        "duration": 212916,
        "annotations": [
            {
                "timestamp": 1511858133393425,
                "value": "cs",
                "endpoint": {
                    "serviceName": "monitor-gw-web",
                    "ipv4": "10.19.138.169"
                }
            },
            {
                "timestamp": 1511858133588237,
                "value": "sr",
                "endpoint": {
                    "serviceName": "monitor-gw-s",
                    "ipv4": "10.19.138.169"
                }
            },
            {
                "timestamp": 1511858133593907,
                "value": "ss",
                "endpoint": {
                    "serviceName": "monitor-gw-s",
                    "ipv4": "10.19.138.169"
                }
            },
            {
                "timestamp": 1511858133606341,
                "value": "cr",
                "endpoint": {
                    "serviceName": "monitor-gw-web",
                    "ipv4": "10.19.138.169"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "traceId": "ae60bd175a61e820",
        "id": "8ef78f0edefe3a4b",
        "name": "data enqueue",
        "parentId": "16eefe087852af41",
        "timestamp": 1511858133592958,
        "duration": 129,
        "binaryAnnotations": [
            {
                "key": "lc",
                "value": "",
                "endpoint": {
                    "serviceName": "monitor-gw-s",
                    "ipv4": "10.19.138.169"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "traceId": "ae60bd175a61e820",
        "id": "97c637bcc891b86a",
        "name": "data dequeue, send to kafka",
        "parentId": "16eefe087852af41",
        "timestamp": 1511858133593147,
        "duration": 2416,
        "binaryAnnotations": [
            {
                "key": "lc",
                "value": "",
                "endpoint": {
                    "serviceName": "monitor-gw-s",
                    "ipv4": "10.19.138.169"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "traceId": "ae60bd175a61e820",
        "id": "f193c7f4193f2879",
        "name": "",
        "parentId": "16eefe087852af41",
        "timestamp": 1511858133594113,
        "duration": 7575,
        "annotations": [
            {
                "timestamp": 1511858133594113,
                "value": "ms",
                "endpoint": {
                    "serviceName": "monitor-gw-s",
                    "ipv4": "10.19.138.169"
                }
            },
            {
                "timestamp": 1511858133601688,
                "value": "ws",
                "endpoint": {
                    "serviceName": "monitor-gw-s",
                    "ipv4": "10.19.138.169"
                }
            }
        ],
        "binaryAnnotations": [
            {
                "key": "kafka.topic",
                "value": "rdkafka",
                "endpoint": {
                    "serviceName": "monitor-gw-s",
                    "ipv4": "10.19.138.169"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "traceId": "ae60bd175a61e820",
        "id": "54a3f6268df0aaee",
        "name": "",
        "parentId": "f193c7f4193f2879",
        "timestamp": 1511858133600067,
        "duration": 5,
        "annotations": [
            {
                "timestamp": 1511858133600067,
                "value": "wr",
                "endpoint": {
                    "serviceName": "monitor-kafka-consumer",
                    "ipv4": "10.19.138.169"
                }
            },
            {
                "timestamp": 1511858133600072,
                "value": "mr",
                "endpoint": {
                    "serviceName": "monitor-kafka-consumer",
                    "ipv4": "10.19.138.169"
                }
            }
        ],
        "binaryAnnotations": [
            {
                "key": "kafka.topic",
                "value": "rdkafka",
                "endpoint": {
                    "serviceName": "monitor-kafka-consumer",
                    "ipv4": "10.19.138.169"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]

It can easy to find that there are 8 spans.

When I use the api to get the trace with the same traceId
        ElasticsearchStorage storage = ElasticsearchStorage.newBuilder()
                .hosts(Arrays.asList("http://10.19.138.169:9200")).build();

```
    List<Span> trace = null;
    try {
        trace = storage.spanStore().getTrace(traceId).execute();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I get 
[
  {
    "traceId": "ae60bd175a61e820",
    "parentId": "16eefe087852af41",
    "id": "97c637bcc891b86a",
    "name": "data dequeue, send to kafka",
    "timestamp": 1511858133593147,
    "duration": 2416,
    "localEndpoint": {
      "serviceName": "monitor-gw-s",
      "ipv4": "10.19.138.169"
    }
  },
  {
    "traceId": "ae60bd175a61e820",
    "id": "ae60bd175a61e820",
    "name": "client",
    "timestamp": 1511858133224433,
    "duration": 508444,
    "localEndpoint": {
      "serviceName": "monitor-gw-http-c",
      "ipv4": "10.19.138.169"
    }
  },
  {
    "traceId": "ae60bd175a61e820",
    "parentId": "f193c7f4193f2879",
    "id": "54a3f6268df0aaee",
    "kind": "CONSUMER",
    "timestamp": 1511858133600067,
    "duration": 5,
    "localEndpoint": {
      "serviceName": "monitor-kafka-consumer",
      "ipv4": "10.19.138.169"
    },
    "tags": {
      "kafka.topic": "rdkafka"
    }
  },
  {
    "traceId": "ae60bd175a61e820",
    "parentId": "ae60bd175a61e820",
    "id": "19d69c3e93bc9040",
    "kind": "SERVER",
    "name": "post",
    "timestamp": 1511858133383290,
    "duration": 226078,
    "localEndpoint": {
      "serviceName": "monitor-gw-web",
      "ipv4": "10.19.138.169"
    },
    "remoteEndpoint": {
      "ipv4": "127.0.0.1",
      "port": 43928
    },
    "tags": {
      "http.path": "/security/gateway"
    },
    "shared": true
  },
  {
    "traceId": "ae60bd175a61e820",
    "parentId": "19d69c3e93bc9040",
    "id": "16eefe087852af41",
    "kind": "CLIENT",
    "name": "ennmonitorsecuritygatewayserver/put",
    "timestamp": 1511858133393425,
    "duration": 212916,
    "localEndpoint": {
      "serviceName": "monitor-gw-web",
      "ipv4": "10.19.138.169"
    }
  },
  {
    "traceId": "ae60bd175a61e820",
    "parentId": "19d69c3e93bc9040",
    "id": "16eefe087852af41",
    "kind": "SERVER",
    "name": "ennmonitorsecuritygatewayserver/put",
    "timestamp": 1511858133588237,
    "duration": 5670,
    "localEndpoint": {
      "serviceName": "monitor-gw-s",
      "ipv4": "10.19.138.169"
    },
    "shared": true
  },
  {
    "traceId": "ae60bd175a61e820",
    "parentId": "16eefe087852af41",
    "id": "f193c7f4193f2879",
    "kind": "PRODUCER",
    "timestamp": 1511858133594113,
    "duration": 7575,
    "localEndpoint": {
      "serviceName": "monitor-gw-s",
      "ipv4": "10.19.138.169"
    },
    "tags": {
      "kafka.topic": "rdkafka"
    }
  },
  {
    "traceId": "ae60bd175a61e820",
    "parentId": "ae60bd175a61e820",
    "id": "19d69c3e93bc9040",
    "kind": "CLIENT",
    "name": "post",
    "timestamp": 1511858133239803,
    "duration": 490921,
    "localEndpoint": {
      "serviceName": "monitor-gw-http-c",
      "ipv4": "10.19.138.169"
    },
    "remoteEndpoint": {
      "ipv4": "127.0.0.1",
      "port": 8090
    },
    "tags": {
      "http.path": "/security/gateway"
    }
  },
  {
    "traceId": "ae60bd175a61e820",
    "parentId": "ae60bd175a61e820",
    "id": "19d69c3e93bc9040",
    "kind": "SERVER",
    "name": "post",
    "timestamp": 1511858133383290,
    "duration": 226078,
    "localEndpoint": {
      "serviceName": "monitor-gw-web",
      "ipv4": "10.19.138.169"
    },
    "remoteEndpoint": {
      "ipv4": "127.0.0.1",
      "port": 43928
    },
    "tags": {
      "http.path": "/security/gateway"
    },
    "shared": true
  },
  {
    "traceId": "ae60bd175a61e820",
    "parentId": "19d69c3e93bc9040",
    "id": "16eefe087852af41",
    "kind": "SERVER",
    "name": "ennmonitorsecuritygatewayserver/put",
    "timestamp": 1511858133588237,
    "duration": 5670,
    "localEndpoint": {
      "serviceName": "monitor-gw-s",
      "ipv4": "10.19.138.169"
    },
    "shared": true
  },
  {
    "traceId": "ae60bd175a61e820",
    "parentId": "16eefe087852af41",
    "id": "97c637bcc891b86a",
    "name": "data dequeue, send to kafka",
    "timestamp": 1511858133593147,
    "duration": 2416,
    "localEndpoint": {
      "serviceName": "monitor-gw-s",
      "ipv4": "10.19.138.169"
    }
  },
  {
    "traceId": "ae60bd175a61e820",
    "parentId": "16eefe087852af41",
    "id": "f193c7f4193f2879",
    "kind": "PRODUCER",
    "timestamp": 1511858133594113,
    "duration": 7575,
    "localEndpoint": {
      "serviceName": "monitor-gw-s",
      "ipv4": "10.19.138.169"
    },
    "tags": {
      "kafka.topic": "rdkafka"
    }
  },
  {
    "traceId": "ae60bd175a61e820",
    "parentId": "19d69c3e93bc9040",
    "id": "16eefe087852af41",
    "kind": "CLIENT",
    "name": "ennmonitorsecuritygatewayserver/put",
    "timestamp": 1511858133393425,
    "duration": 212916,
    "localEndpoint": {
      "serviceName": "monitor-gw-web",
      "ipv4": "10.19.138.169"
    }
  },
  {
    "traceId": "ae60bd175a61e820",
    "parentId": "ae60bd175a61e820",
    "id": "19d69c3e93bc9040",
    "kind": "CLIENT",
    "name": "post",
    "timestamp": 1511858133239803,
    "duration": 490921,
    "localEndpoint": {
      "serviceName": "monitor-gw-http-c",
      "ipv4": "10.19.138.169"
    },
    "remoteEndpoint": {
      "ipv4": "127.0.0.1",
      "port": 8090
    },
    "tags": {
      "http.path": "/security/gateway"
    }
  },
  {
    "traceId": "ae60bd175a61e820",
    "id": "ae60bd175a61e820",
    "name": "client",
    "timestamp": 1511858133224433,
    "duration": 508444,
    "localEndpoint": {
      "serviceName": "monitor-gw-http-c",
      "ipv4": "10.19.138.169"
    }
  },
  {
    "traceId": "ae60bd175a61e820",
    "parentId": "f193c7f4193f2879",
    "id": "54a3f6268df0aaee",
    "kind": "CONSUMER",
    "timestamp": 1511858133600067,
    "duration": 5,
    "localEndpoint": {
      "serviceName": "monitor-kafka-consumer",
      "ipv4": "10.19.138.169"
    },
    "tags": {
      "kafka.topic": "rdkafka"
    }
  },
  {
    "traceId": "ae60bd175a61e820",
    "parentId": "16eefe087852af41",
    "id": "8ef78f0edefe3a4b",
    "name": "data enqueue",
    "timestamp": 1511858133592958,
    "duration": 129,
    "localEndpoint": {
      "serviceName": "monitor-gw-s",
      "ipv4": "10.19.138.169"
    }
  },
  {
    "traceId": "ae60bd175a61e820",
    "parentId": "16eefe087852af41",
    "id": "8ef78f0edefe3a4b",
    "name": "data enqueue",
    "timestamp": 1511858133592958,
    "duration": 129,
    "localEndpoint": {
      "serviceName": "monitor-gw-s",
      "ipv4": "10.19.138.169"
    }
  }
]

It is easy to find that there are 18 spans.

It seems that some of spans are merged in the web request, I want to know to where is the cource code deal this.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The first request uses v1 of the Zipkin api while the second uses v2 (see https://github.com/openzipkin/zipkin/issues/1499 for the v2 specification). Spans are broken up by kind (SERVER and CLIENT) instead of having client receive, server receive, client send, and server send annotations (hence why there are more spans).